# Updating an attribute of an element in list with matching attribute

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8. I have a list of objects of class A, where structure of A is as follows:

```
class A {
   int name,
   boolean isActive
}
```

Now I have a list of elements L of class A, in that list I want to update an element having name="test" with inactive=false.

I can do this very easily by writing a for loop and creating a new list.

But how would I do that using Java 8 stream API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
L.stream()
.filter(item-> item.getName().equals("test"))
.forEachOrdered(a -> a.setActiv(false));
```

I believe data type of name should be `String` not `int` in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
yourList.replaceAll(x -> {
    if(x.getName().equals("SomeName")){
        x.setIsActive(false);
        return x;
    }
    return x;
})
```