# Change attribute of an object in ArrayList

Tags: java-8

I would like to modify an attribute of an object in an Arraylist. For example :

```
class A {
    String text;
    boolean bool;

    // getters and setters....
}
```

If I have an `ArrayList<A>` in an other class, how can I modify the attribute of a given `String text` (which is in an object in the ArrayList)

I know it's possible on java 8 with collections and stream but I can't figure how to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275913/updating-an-attribute-of-an-element-in-list-with-matching-attribute/49276103#49276103

Comment: Great thank you, I didn't see this answers

Comment: @Eugene Thank you. You are really fast. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
list.forEach(a -> a.setText("some new value"));
```

Comment: You don’t need to use a stream here. Just call the forEach directly on the list.

Comment: yeah you are right.