# Find then replace/add using Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8. I have a list of elements of class A as follows:

```
class A {
   String name,
   boolean isActive
}
```

As per my use case, if any input element e comes, I will first check if there any existing element with the same name as e and isActive = false, then we will replace that element with setting isActive = true, else we will add the new element e.

I can do that by writing one for loop for finding if any element exists and then replace/add. But can we do these two in a single step using java 8?

EDIT : The code I have written is as follows:

```
   A a = aList.stream()
                .filter(item -> item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(input.getName())).findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
   if (a == null) {
          aList.add(a.builder().isActive("true").name(input.getName).build());
    } else {
          aList.stream()
                    .filter(item -> item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(input.getName()))
                    .forEach(a -> a.setIsActive("true"));
   }
```

Comment: why would you ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275913/updating-an-attribute-of-an-element-in-list-with-matching-attribute

Comment: @Eugene No it is not a duplicate question, may be related.

Comment: if its not, post the code in the plain loop that you have in mind